# Disable repetitive schema lookups by MySql Connector/Net

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I'm troubleshooting a .Net application using MySql Connector/Net 6.8.3. Performance is terrible for a number of reasons, one of which is that the following query is run against the database every time a stored proc is called:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA LIKE 'myschema' AND ROUTINE_NAME LIKE 'myproc';
```

It appears to me that MySql Connector is checking the stored proc exists (and presumably checking the parameters) every time the proc is called. Cumulatively this adds a lot of overhead because of the number of stored procedure calls.

Is there a convenient way to turn off this behaviour, or perhaps cache information about the stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a bug in the .Net driver for MySQL. It is described here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74116

(Oracle were kind enough to send me [a t-shirt for submitting a patch](http://www.dovetail.ie/blog/2014/open-source-for-fun-and-profit-and-a-t-shirt/), though it doesn't appear to have been incorporated yet.)

Comment: I would like this fix, but don't want the hassle of building the source and manually patching it. What's taking Oracle so long?